# What is lsqcurvefit actually returning for the Jacobian?

Tags: matlab

When performing a nonlinear least squares fit with `lsqcurvefit`, and getting the Jacobian as an output (i.e. `[x,resnorm,residual,exitflag,output,lambda,jacobian] = lsqcurvefit(...)`), I get a 6x6 matrix for the Jacobian. The number of parameters in the state I'm estimating is 6, and the number of dimensions in the measurements is 2, so I would expect a 2x6 matrix. What's going on here?

Comment: How many observation points do you have?

Comment: @macduff I have three observation points in this case.

Comment: What are your optimization `optimset` settings?  When I invoke this function, I get dimensions that are like `number of states` X `number of observations`, can you post a trimmed down version of your problem so I can recreate it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I figured it out. Since I have three 2x1 observations, internally `lsqcurvefit` is  storing them as a 6x1 vector instead of the way I was thinking of them (2x3 matrix) (see [Linear Indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#f1-85511)). This is partly because of the unclear documentation and partly because of a misunderstanding of least squares on my part.

Anyway, the Jacobian that is returned is essentially three 2x6 Jacobians (partials of the observation set i with respect to the 6-dimensional state) stacked on top of each other, which is expected behavior for a least squares Jacobian. If I had a fourth observation, the Jacobian would be 8x6.